# How to use delegate in React Native?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, design-patterns, delegation

Is there a way of delegating in react native just like in swift/ios.. If we want to pass a information to a child class from parent class, we can do it by passing props. But what if we want to pass some information from the child class to parent class.

PS: No Redux or singleton approach.

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are common in React and could be used for such a thing.

```js
// Child.js
export default class Child extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onEvent({ type : "event" });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Text>I'm a child</Text>
        );
    }
}
```

```js
// Parent.js
export default class Parent extends Component {

    const onChildEvent = (event) => {
        console.log(event); // { type : "event" }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Child onEvent={this.onChildEvent} />
        );
    }
}
```